# I’m searching for short-story or novel where whole planet was grass-like stuff

Tags: story-identification

There’s a long short-story, or maybe a novel where an astronaut crash-lands on a planet where a grass-like species dominates the entire ecosystem. At least on land, he sees some dolphin-like creatures in the ocean. I believe the grass in inedible, and he eventually dies after subsisting on algae. It was released some time after *All Flesh is Grass* by Clifford Simak, because I remember my dad also had that but it was older (and not about a grassworld).

Comment: Maybe the same as this (unanswered)  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226322/looking-for-a-short-story-i-read-in-85-86?r=SearchResults

Comment: Bob Shaw's *Orbitsville* is about a Dyson sphere whose interior is covered in grassland.  I don't remember the other plot points though, so just commenting.